# Unexpected action with WM_PAINT when window is uncovered

Tags: windows

I've written a simple Windows program which traps on WM_PAINT to execute a single line via TextOut.
My understanding is that if all or a portion of the client area is covered up by another app, a WM_PAINT msg is sent to WndProc requiring the invalidated area to be re-drawn. What I find is that covering the window with another app doesn't cause WM_PAINT to be issued and the window redraws itself seamlessly. However, if I minimize the window and then maximize it again the WM_PAINT msg is received and I need to repaint.
When using another app to cover up the window I tried all degrees of cover including a total cover.
The WNDCLASSEX struc has CS_HREDRAW and CS_VREDRAW. The window is created with WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW and WS_VISIBLE.
CS_HREDRAW and CS_VREDRAW are documented as coming into effect when the window is moved or resized but not when covered.
Thanks in advance for any help.
afk

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_Window_Manager